# Is $\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 100^\circ}\cdot \sec 100^\circ = 1$ or $-1$?

Tags: trigonometry

The equation will simplify to

\begin{align}
& = \sqrt{\cos^2 100^\circ}\cdot \sec100^\circ \\[8pt]
& = \cos100^\circ\cdot\sec100^\circ \\[8pt]
& = 1
\end{align}

But the answer key says that the correct answer is $-1$?

Comment: The answer key is correct; the cosine of $100^{\circ}$ is negative.

Comment: @egreg but so is secaant of 100∘, so wouldn't they completely cancel out leaving the answer to be 1?

Comment: @egreg,I am not sure why that should matter.$\cos$ and $\sec$ both have the same sign.

Comment: @rah4927 The fact is that $\cos100\ne\sqrt{1-\sin^2100}$. Just so simple.

Comment: What is $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$?

Comment: @egreg,ah,so since $\cos100$ is negative,and the the square root gives us a non-negative value,we must have $-\cos100$ .

Comment: @rah4927 yes except that you used the two times.

Comment: @Awesome,I don't get the second part of your comment.

Comment: @rah4927 read your previous comment.

Comment: @Awesome,sorry I am still unable to see what I used two times.

Comment: @rah4927 read after "negative, and"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. So $\cos100$ will be negative because in the second quadrant. So $\sqrt{\cos^2100}=-\cos100$.

Comment: So is the square root function essentially the same modulus?

Comment: @Niharika No. It's a typo. See my answer

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$ ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Root of $\cos(100)^2$ is always positive. So root of $\cos(100)^2$ is also positive. And the value of root of $1-\sin(100)^2$ will be $+\cos100$. Now $\sec100$ is negative, so the value is $1/-\cos100$. So $\cos100$ and $-\cos100$ get cancelled and we get -1 as the answer.